# Dota 2 trading terms

Tags: terminology, dota-2

I have perused some dota 2 trading forums.  Certain items/terms are appearing often, but I'm just not sure what the jargon means.

The terms 
 - Hook
 - TB
 - Old Key

They are what I am unsure about.

I've seen some people jokingly refer to the "hook" as Kunkka's pirate hook, though I'm fairly certain that's not really what it is.  I doubt TB stands for tuberculosis.  And, what is an "old key" compared to any other key?

Comment: Hook = Pudge's Bone Hook. TB = Vintage Timebreaker, a weapon for Faceless Void. Old key refers to the regular Treasure Keys, "new" key usually refers to the current promotional key that you need to open certain new chests. Currently new keys refer to the Dark treasure chest keys, which open the "Treasure of Dark Implements" chest.

Comment: @Kotsu I think you're right on "new" keys, but I think there's a difference still between "old" keys and regular keys.

Comment: No, I don't believe there is. Old key does refer to standard keys. New Key applies to whatever is currently the temporary promo key.

Comment: @Kotsu You should probably make that an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there is a lot of terminology/slang out there for Dota 2 trading, the ones you ask about are:

- **Hook**: Pudge's Bone Hook.
- **TB**: Vintage Timebreaker, a weapon for Faceless Void
- **Old Key**: Refers to the regular Treasure Keys that are $2.50 USD in the store
- **New Key**: Refers to the current promotional key that you need to open certain new chests. As of January 2013, new keys refer to the Dark treasure chest keys, which open the "Treasure of Dark Implements" chest.